# mysql select most recent row by date for each user

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to select the most recent rows for every unique userid where pid = 50 and active = 1.  I haven't been able to figure it out.

Here is a sample table

```
+-----+----------+-------+-----------------------+---------+
| id  | userid   | pid   | start_date            | active  |
+-----+----------+-------+-----------------------+---------+
| 1   | 4        | 50    | 2015-05-15 12:00:00   | 1       |
| 2   | 4        | 50    | 2015-05-16 12:00:00   | 1       |
| 3   | 4        | 50    | 2015-05-17 12:00:00   | 0       |
| 4   | 4        | 51    | 2015-06-29 12:00:00   | 1       |
| 5   | 4        | 51    | 2015-06-30 12:00:00   | 1       |
| 6   | 5        | 50    | 2015-07-05 12:00:00   | 1       |
| 7   | 5        | 50    | 2015-07-06 12:00:00   | 1       |
| 8   | 5        | 51    | 2015-07-08 12:00:00   | 1       |
+-----+----------+-------+-----------------------+---------+
```

Desired Result

```
+-----+----------+-------+-----------------------+---------+
| id  | userid   | pid   | start_date            | active  |
+-----+----------+-------+-----------------------+---------+
| 2   | 4        | 50    | 2015-05-16 12:00:00   | 1       |
| 7   | 5        | 50    | 2015-07-06 12:00:00   | 1       |
+-----+----------+-------+-----------------------+---------+
```

I've tried a bunch of things and this is the closest I got but unfortunately it is not quit there.

```
SELECT *
FROM mytable t1
WHERE
    (
        SELECT COUNT(*)
        FROM mytable t2
        WHERE
            t1.userid = t2.userid           
            AND t1.start_date < t2.start_date
    ) < 1
AND pid = 50
AND active = 1
ORDER BY start_date DESC
```

Comment: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/example-maximum-column-group-row.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**plan**

> 1. get last record grouping by userid where pid is 50 and is active
> 2. inner join to mytable to get the record info associated with last

---

**query**

```
select 
my.*
from
(
select userid, pid, active, max(start_date) as lst
from mytable
where pid = 50
and   active = 1
group by userid, pid, active
) maxd
inner join mytable my
on  maxd.userid = my.userid
and maxd.pid    = my.pid
and maxd.active = my.active
and maxd.lst    = my.start_date
;
```

**output**

```
+----+--------+-----+------------------------+--------+
| id | userid | pid |       start_date       | active |
+----+--------+-----+------------------------+--------+
|  2 |      4 |  50 | May, 16 2015 12:00:00  |      1 |
|  7 |      5 |  50 | July, 06 2015 12:00:00 |      1 |
+----+--------+-----+------------------------+--------+
```

[sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/9d5dc/10)

**notes**

as suggested by @Strawberry, updated to join also on pid and active. this will avoid the possibility of a record which is not active or not pid 50 but has exact same date also being rendered.

Comment: That's it! Looks like I was a ways away from getting that right.  I appreciate your time and great answer.

Comment: @Strawberry yes could also do that ( projecting those fields, grouping by and adding to join ). is there an advantage in doing so ?

Comment: Only in the unlikely event that two rows for a given user share the same max date - but it's unclear what the natural key on this table would be

Comment: @Strawberry updated to avoid printing record with possible start_date collision ( but not active or 50 )

Comment: figured - but in the interests of technical accuracy ;)